# Set Cufon Text Width

Tags: javascript, width, cufon

I have this cufon generated Chinese title that can't be extended to multiple lines when the text is too long. To put simply, it can't do word wrap. I've tried to limit the width of the parent container (an h2). but that doesn't seem to apply. Anything else I can try?

Angela

Comment: Have u tried any formatting with css or the style attribute?

Comment: Yes, first to the parent, which doesn't do anything at all. Then, I applied it directly on the cufon canvas, which causes the canvas to disappear completely.

Comment: Have you used the style attribute? So <h2 style = "text-align:center;">Hi</h2>